# Permission denied accessing Selenium Manager in Github Actions

Tags: github, selenium-webdriver, github-actions

I'm having an issue trying to run C# selenium tests with GitHub actions. Tests run fine locally, but when executed through GitHub actions, I get the following error:

```
Error Message:
   OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchDriverException : Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Error starting process: /home/runner/work/InvoiceCloudTechnicalChallenge/InvoiceCloudTechnicalChallenge/bin/Debug/net7.0/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager  --browser "chrome" --output json
  ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : An error occurred trying to start process '/home/runner/work/InvoiceCloudTechnicalChallenge/InvoiceCloudTechnicalChallenge/bin/Debug/net7.0/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager' with working directory '/home/runner/work/InvoiceCloudTechnicalChallenge/InvoiceCloudTechnicalChallenge/bin/Debug/net7.0'. Permission denied
```

I'm new to GitHub actions and not quite sure how to grant permissions to a folder running in a GitHub container. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the [public repo](https://github.com/cjohnsontx1/InvoiceCloudTechnicalChallenge) used for testing.

[Many failed attempts](https://github.com/cjohnsontx1/InvoiceCloudTechnicalChallenge/actions) at getting the actions to work.

Comment: Have you visited https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location and tried any suggested solutions?